# Create .jar files in java without using IDE

Tags: java

I am trying to create .jar files in java which can be used by including it in other projects. It doesn't contain any main but only classes and methods. I am using th following command to create .jar file from command line

```
jar cf firstjar.jar *
```

I am including the jar file in my project but still the class is not available in the project.
What's the problem in this.

Comment: What files does the * pick up?

Comment: Define "available in the project"--how are you trying to *make* it available in the project?

Comment: 1) Rename jar to zip (jar is actually a zip archive). Open it and see if it contains all required classes. 2) if it does, could you tell more about how you are including the jar in your project

Comment: I am creating the project in Eclipse IDE and including the jar by adding it via build path in eclipse

Comment: And what directory are you doing this in? What does your package structure look like, and what does the directory structure in your jar file look like?

Comment: Once added to the buildpath Eclipse will allow you to open the jar-file like any other folder. If you do you should see the content you packed into the jar file. Are the content of the file in the way you expect them? Are you aware that you need to put the compiled java-class files and not the java-source files into the jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My *guess* is that you've got a problem with the directory structure.

Suppose you have a class like this:

```
package org.foo;

public class Bar {}
```

There should be `Bar.class` flie in a directory `org/foo`. That structure has to be in the jar file as well - so you should go to the directory *containing* `org` and run:

```
jar cf firstjar.jar org
```

(Or whatever your top-level package name is.)

If you just include the classfiles *from the `foo` directory* then Java's expectations of where to find things will be invalid.